# How to display year in jQuery countdown timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, countdown

I have a countdown timer for next 25 years. how can I display years in this timer. currently instead of year days are showing. I need to display the years also. please help .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moayL.png)

please find the code i have used
"code"

```
enter code here

 let daysItem = document.querySelector("#days");
 let hoursItem = document.querySelector("#hours");
 let minItem = document.querySelector("#min");
 let secItem = document.querySelector("#sec");

 let countDown = () => {
 let futureDate = new Date("17 august 2022 9:59:59");
 let currentDate = new Date();
 let myDate = futureDate - currentDate;
 //console.log(myDate);

 let days = Math.floor(myDate / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24);

 let hours = Math.floor(myDate / 1000 / 60 / 60) % 24;

 let min = Math.floor(myDate / 1000 / 60) % 60;

 let sec = Math.floor(myDate / 1000) % 60;

 daysItem.innerHTML = days;
 hoursItem.innerHTML = hours;
 minItem.innerHTML = min;
 secItem.innerHTML = sec;
}

countDown()

setInterval(countDown, 1000)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make calculation with getFullYear() from current date to futur date.

```js
let yearsItem = document.querySelector("#years");
let daysItem = document.querySelector("#days");
let hoursItem = document.querySelector("#hours");
let minItem = document.querySelector("#min");
let secItem = document.querySelector("#sec");

let countDown = () => {
 let futureDate = new Date("17 august 2047 9:59:59");
 let currentDate = new Date();
 let myDate = futureDate - currentDate;
 //console.log(myDate);

 let years = futureDate.getFullYear() - currentDate.getFullYear(); 
 
 let days = Math.floor(myDate / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24);

 let hours = Math.floor(myDate / 1000 / 60 / 60) % 24;

 let min = Math.floor(myDate / 1000 / 60) % 60;

 let sec = Math.floor(myDate / 1000) % 60;
 
 yearsItem.innerHTML = years;
 daysItem.innerHTML = days;
 hoursItem.innerHTML = hours;
 minItem.innerHTML = min;
 secItem.innerHTML = sec;
}

countDown()

setInterval(countDown, 1000)
```

```css
div { display:inline-block; padding:5px; background:#000; color:#fff }
```

```html
Years <div id="years"></div>
Days <div id="days"></div>
Hours <div id="hours"></div>
Min <div id="min"></div>
Sec <div id="sec"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks . but here date is wrong. 23 YEARS- 295 DAYS, 10 hours, 10 min, 3 sec like that i need

Comment: You where asking for years, that's what i did. @sanishmashylendran

Comment: Note that Stackoverflow is not free coding website. We help if you get stuck in your codes developments.